# JavaFX TableView how to get file size to PropertyValueFactory?

Tags: file, javafx, tableview

I have some TableView with two columns - name and size;
This Table works with File objects;

PropertyValueFactory for columns can take properties of object, trying search somenameProrperty, getSomename, isSomename;
I'm need to get length() method from File.

```
columnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
columnSize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("length"));
```

This code view file names (getName() method), but length colums is empty. 
Know anyone what i can do with factory to get length() from File?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the cell value factory directly, instead of using the convenience (and somewhat legacy) class `PropertyValueFactory`.

Assuming your `columnSize` is a `TableColumn<File, Number>`, you can do

```
columnSize.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleLongProperty(cellData.getValue().length()));
```

If you want to format the data in the column more elegantly, you can additionally set a cell factory:

```
columnSize.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<File, Number>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number length, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(length, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(formatFileLength(length.longValue()));
        }
    }
});

// ...

private String formatFileLength(long length) {
    final String[] unitNames = {"bytes", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"};
    int i ;
    for (i = 0 ; length > 1024 && i < unitNames.length - 1 ; i++) {
        length = length / 1024 ;
    }
    return String.format("%,d %s", length, unitNames[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Found solution

```
columnSize.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<File, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<File, String> param) {
        long size = param.getValue().length();
        size = size/1024;
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(String.valueOf(size));
    }
});
```